# Using Fortify to scan Java sources which uses Lombok annotations

Tags: java, lombok, fortify

We are using HP Fortify to scan our java code, and it errors outs where it cannot resolve methods generated by lombok annotations such as @Getter. Any Fortify experts know how to get Fortify to honor these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since SCA works on source files, it can't see all the extras that lombok adds to your class files.

You could try using [Delombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) to get a set of source files that include everything lombok adds to the class and then translate those with SCA.

Or, you could translate the lombok generated class files directly; SCA supports translating Java Bytecode.

P.S. you should contact Fortify support and let them know you want support for Lombok; enhancement requests are tracked by customer demand.